# How to reference IResult in ASP.NET Core 7

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, minimal-apis

I've created a minimal web API in .NET 7 and I am trying to extract some of the code to a separate assembly. This code is using [IResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iresult?view=aspnetcore-7.0), which was introduced in .NET 7.

How do I reference `IResult` from a regular class library?

According to MSDN, the type is supposed to be in the assembly `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll` in the NuGet `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref` v7.0.3, but that is a platform component that cannot be referenced directly by assemblies.

Comment: Have you tried changing your csproj file to be `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, the referencing works then, but it will change the project from class library to a web application, which requires a main entry method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a class library using `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`, you'll need to add a `FrameworkReference`.

```xml
<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
```

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework).

> As of .NET Core 3.0, projects using the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` MSBuild SDK implicitly reference the shared framework. Projects using the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` or `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` SDK must reference ASP.NET Core to use ASP.NET Core APIs in the shared framework.

Your `.csproj` file might look like below.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Both solution, documentation and example. Much appreciated!